Is there any historical data for the bid/ask spread on NASDAQ at the close?
Using Google, I see that the average bid/ask spread on NASDAQ is 1.0133% (of the price). But I also see that the spread narrows towards the closing bell along with the higher volume. Does anyone know of any historical data where I can find the average bid/ask spread at the close of the market for NASDAQ stocks?
